# Use a Register as a Parameter to DB (MASM)

Tags: assembly, masm, cpu-registers

I have an integer stored in register `edx` containing a random value from 0 to 255 (0x00 to 0xFF) and I want to use its value as a parameter for `db`.

```
db edx
```

However, when I attempt to do that I get error [A2138](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev15.query?appId=Dev15IDEF1&k=k(A2138)) saying "invalid data initializer".

To be clear, a command like

```
db 57
```

does work, just not the one shown previously.

So I suppose the question I'm asking is how can I use a register as a parameter to the `db` command?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: db is interpreted by the assembler.  If you want to `mov` a value from a register into memory during runtime, you will need to use the `mov` instruction.  Also, be aware the db refers to bytes, while edx is a 32bit value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. `db` is telling the compiler to put a value defined after the `db` as it is during the compile time.

With the register, you can't do this as the value is unknown (well it's known and equal to zero) that's why you're getting an error. If you want to put a value from register you need to use a mov opcode.

```
loc db ?
....
mov [loc], dl
```

Since `edx` is 32-bit we can't store it in `db` so either we store the lowest 8-bit or we need to change the `loc` to be `dd`.